# Mysql attack prevention

Tags: mysql

i am currently developing a API for a service and was wondering if this could be classed as safe enough to prevent injection and/or other malicious attacks to the databases.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_REQUEST['username']));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_REQUEST['password']));
```

What this is doing is stripping out everything but letters and numbers and then running the mysql_real_escape_string command to run a fine comb in case something managed to get though.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string alone is enough for preventing mysql injections (as long as you run all user input through it)

Comment: Also, I hope you [hash your passwords](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html).  And use a salt.  (The best choice would be to use [PBKDF2](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard), but any decent salted hash is better than storing passwords unhashed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the deprecated [`ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) function and just use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Also, why would you want to limit the user's password to a subset of chars. This just makes breaking in much easier.

Comment: Thanks dude, if this is putting users accounts at risk, then i will remove this right away, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: It's not. It's just unnecessary and too restrictive. myslq_real_escape_string alone is sufficient to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Just your regex would be enough, without any further cleaning.

However, you should consider creating some sort of layer between your forms and the database to do this cleaning automatically.

Comment: Assuming you have a valid reason for allowing only alphnumerics, the regex would be enough.

Comment: regex is depreciated so it wouldn't be the best idea to use it, right?

Comment: @nblackburn: regex isn't, just the `ereg_*()` family of functions. Use `preg_*()`.

Comment: regex certainly isn't deprecated, just the ereg_replace.  Use preg_replace instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nathaniel,

Should be fine your usernames (maybe add '_' to the RE) but you've got a real problem with passwords, haven't you? Any half decent authentication actively encourages a user to choose a password which contain symbol(s), as well as letters, UPPERCASE LETTERS, and numbers.

So I guess I'd just stick to using **[mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) - Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement** ... after CAREFULLY reading the documentation, of course.

Cheers mate. Keith.